# Getting started with xlwings

Tags: xlwings

I'm a reasonably experienced Excel developer and recently watched a couple of video demos of xlwings. I decided to learn more, but I'm finding it very difficult getting started. Do I need Python or other programs installed on my PC before installing xlwings? Are there VBA references I need to set up in advance? Any clues you can provide to this rank beginner will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

xlwings is a Python package and hence you need a Python installation to get started. Have a look at dependencies listed under http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/installation.html. Note that the [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) distribution gets you started most easily as it is a single-click installer that already comes with xlwings and all the dependencies preinstalled.